# Conditional mean and co-variance in $VAR(p)$ conditional on one lag only

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, conditional-expectation, state-space-models

Suppose I have a $p$'th order vector auto regression

$$\vec Z_t = F_1\vec Z_{t-1}+F_2\vec Z_{t-2} + \cdots +F_p \vec Z_{t - p} 
  + \vec \epsilon_t,\qquad \vec\epsilon_t\sim N_q(\vec0,Q)$$

where $Z_t\in\mathbb{R}^q$. Then we can put this into the state-space form

\begin{aligned}
\vec X_t &= (\vec Z_t,\vec Z_{t-1},\dots, \vec Z_{t - p + 1}) \\
\vec X_t &= F\vec X_{t-1} + R\vec\epsilon_t\\
F &= \begin{pmatrix}
 F_1    & \cdots & \cdots & F_{p-1} & F_p \\
 I_q    & 0      & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 0      &  I_q    & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 \vdots & \ddots & \ddots &0 & 0 \\
 0      & \cdots & 0 & I_q & 0 
\end{pmatrix} & 
R &= \begin{pmatrix} I_q \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}

It follows that the conditional mean is

\begin{aligned}
E(\vec X_{t + p} \mid \vec X_t = \vec x)&= 
    E(\vec E(\vec X_{t + p} \mid \vec X_{t + p - 1}) \mid \vec X_t = \vec x) \\
   &= E(F\vec X_{t + p -1} \mid \vec X_t = \vec x) = \cdots = F^p\vec x
\end{aligned}

and for the conditional covariance, we use that

\begin{aligned}
\vec Z_{t+h} &\propto \sum_{i = 1}^h G(h-i)\vec \epsilon_{t + i} \\
G(k) &=\left\{\begin{matrix}
I_q & k = 0 \\
\sum_{i = 1}^{\min (k, p)}F_iG(k-i) & k > 0
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{aligned}

Thus,

\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}(\vec Z_{t+h}\mid \vec X_t) &= 
   \sum_{i=1}^h G(h-i)QG(h-i)^\top \\
\text{cov}(\vec Z_{t+h}, \vec Z_{t+l}\mid \vec X_t) &= 
\text{cov}\left(
   \sum_{i = 1}^h G(h-i)\vec \epsilon_{t + i}, 
   \sum_{i = 1}^l G(l-i)\vec \epsilon_{t + i} \mid \vec X_t\right) \\
&= \text{cov}\left(
   \sum_{i = 1}^l G(h-i)\vec \epsilon_{t + i}, 
   \sum_{i = 1}^l G(l-i)\vec \epsilon_{t + i} \mid \vec X_t\right) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^l G(h-i)QG(l-i)^\top
\end{aligned}

where I assume that $h > l$. I hope the above is correct though this is not the question. My question is what are similar expressions if we only condition on $Z_t$ and not $X_t= (\vec Z_t,\vec Z_{t-1}, \vec Z_{t - p + 1})$? **I.e., what are**

$$
E(\vec X_{t+p}\mid \vec Z_t),\qquad
\text{Var}(\vec Z_{t+h}\mid \vec Z_t),\qquad
\text{Cov}(\vec Z_{t+h},\vec Z_{t+l}\mid \vec Z_t),\qquad
h > l > 0
$$

---

## Update

Say

$$
\vec X_0 \sim N(\vec \mu_0, Q_0)
$$

which we either set to be the stationary distribution or a distribution selected for convenience. Then

$$
\vec Z_k = \sum_{i = 1}^k G(k-i)\vec \epsilon_i + R^\top F^k\vec X_0
$$

and thus,

\begin{align*}
E(\vec Z_k) &= 
    R^\top F^k\vec\mu_0 \\
\text{Var}(\vec Z_k) &= 
    \sum_{i = 1}^k G(k-i)QG(k-i)^\top + R^\top F^kQ_0F^{k\top} R \\
\text{Cov}(\vec Z_k, \vec Z_l) &= 
    \sum_{i = 1}^l G(k-i)QG(l-i)^\top + R^\top F^kQ_0F^{l\top} R, 
    & k &> l > 0
\end{align*}

Using the above, we can compute the joint mean and covariance matrix and find that

\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix} \vec X_{t+p} \\ \vec Z_t \end{pmatrix}  = 
\begin{pmatrix} \vec Z_{t + p} \\ \vec Z_{t + p - 1} \\ \vdots \\ 
     \vec Z_t \end{pmatrix}
& \sim N\left(\vec\mu, \Sigma \right) \\
\vec\mu &= (E(\vec X_{t+p})^\top, E(\vec Z_t)^\top)^\top\\
\Sigma &= \begin{pmatrix} 
      \text{Var}(\vec X_{t+p}) & \text{Cov}(\vec X_{t+p}, \vec Z_t) \\
      \text{Cov}(\vec Z_t,\vec X_{t+p}) & \text{Var}(\vec Z_t)
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}

From which it is follows that

\begin{aligned}
\vec X_{t+p} \mid \vec Z_t = \vec z &\sim 
  N(k_\vec z, K_\vec z) \\
k_\vec z &= E(\vec X_{t+p}) + \text{Cov}(\vec X_{t+p}, \vec Z_t)
    \text{Var}(\vec Z_t)^{-1}(\vec z - E(\vec Z_t)) \\
K_\vec z &= \text{Var}(\vec X_{t+p}) - 
    \text{Cov}(\vec X_{t+p}, \vec Z_t)
    \text{Var}(\vec Z_t)^{-1}
    \text{Cov}(\vec Z_t, \vec X_{t+p})
\end{aligned}

**Is the above correct? Can I simplify the final expression further to something that is faster to compute or neater?** I gather the latter is simple when we have stationary model since the unconditional means and covariances are independent of time. **What about in the non-stationary case where we assume some distribution for $\vec X_0$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that we are in the univariate case with $E(z_t) = 0$ and the process is stationary. Then

\begin{aligned}
\vec X_{t+p} \mid Z_t = z & \sim N(\vec\beta z, K_{Z}) \\
\vec\beta &=\text{Cov}(\vec X_{t+p}, Z_t)
    \text{Var}(Z_t)^{-1} \\
K_\vec z &= \text{Var}(\vec X_{t+p}) - 
    \text{Cov}(\vec X_{t+p},Z_t)
    \text{Var}(Z_t)^{-1}
    \text{Cov}(Z_t, \vec X_{t+p})
\end{aligned}

and this is easy to check. E.g., consider a univariate $AR(3)$ model

$$
z_t = \phi_1z_{t-1} + \phi_2z_{t-2}+\phi_3z_{t-3} + \epsilon_t,
    \qquad\epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)
$$

then here is an example where we can confirm the result

```r
# assign loadings
p <- 3L
F. <- matrix(0., p, p)
F.[1, ] <- c(0.1, 0.5, 0.25)                      # phi_1, phi_2, phi_3
F.[2:p, 1:(p - 1L)] <- diag(p - 1L)

# get time-invariant covariance matrix
sig <- .2                                         # sigma 
get_Q_0 <- function(F., sig){
  p <- nrow(F.)
  Q <- matrix(c(sig^2, numeric(p * p - 1L)), p, p)
  eg <- eigen(F.)
  las <- eg$values
  U <- eg$vectors
  T. <- solve(U, t(solve(U, Q)))
  Z <- T./(1 - tcrossprod(las))
  Re(tcrossprod(U %*% Z, U))
}
Q_0 <- get_Q_0(F., sig)

# add an extra state
F_aug <- matrix(0., p + 1L, p + 1L)
F_aug[1:p, 1:p] <- F.
F_aug[p + 1L, p] <- 1
F_aug
#R      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#R [1,]  0.1  0.5 0.25    0
#R [2,]  1.0  0.0 0.00    0
#R [3,]  0.0  1.0 0.00    0
#R [4,]  0.0  0.0 1.00    0


# get Sigma
Sigma <- get_Q_0(F_aug, sig)

# coefficients
beta <- Sigma[1:p, p + 1L] * Sigma[p + 1L, p + 1L]^(-1)
beta
#R [1] 0.592 0.691 0.545

# compute conditional covariance matrix
K <- Sigma[1:p, 1:p] - 
  tcrossprod(Sigma[1:p, p + 1L], 
             Sigma[p + 1L, p + 1L]^(-1) *  Sigma[p + 1L, 1:p])
K
#R        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
#R [1,] 0.0575 0.0121 0.0326
#R [2,] 0.0121 0.0462 0.0149
#R [3,] 0.0326 0.0149 0.0622

#####
# simulate Z and X and fit linear regression model
set.seed(73408077)
n_sim <- 100000L
tmp <- crossprod(chol(Q_0), matrix(rnorm(p * n_sim), p))
tmp <- rbind(F.[1,] %*% tmp + rnorm(n_sim, sd = sig), tmp)
X <- t(tmp)[, 1:p]
Z <- tmp[p + 1L, ]

fit <- lm(X ~ Z - 1)
coef(fit)
#R    [,1] [,2]  [,3]
#R Z 0.593 0.69 0.546
beta # should be
#R [1] 0.592 0.691 0.545

# estimated conditional covariance matrix
crossprod(residuals(fit)) / (n_sim - p)
#R        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
#R [1,] 0.0573 0.0121 0.0326
#R [2,] 0.0121 0.0464 0.0149
#R [3,] 0.0326 0.0149 0.0620
K # should be
#R        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
#R [1,] 0.0575 0.0121 0.0326
#R [2,] 0.0121 0.0462 0.0149
#R [3,] 0.0326 0.0149 0.0622
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your own question for the benefit of all other users who might be facing the same problem.